# How to submit form with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="check_form();"></div>
```

If all fields are corrects function `check_form()` return true, I want submit form, only hwen all fields are correct, how to do it. On this moments when I close JavaScript alerts form auto submit.

Comment: if the validation fails, `return false;` to prevent the default behavior (which is to submit the page), otherwise `return true;` and let it submit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the return

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return check_form();"></div>
```

and your function

```
function check_form(){
    var isValid = true;
    if(.....) {
        isValid = false;
    } 
    return isValid;
}
```

better yet use `onsubmit` of the form since an Enter key in a textbox can submit it.